# What is /^ and /i in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Recently I downloaded a source (LevBot) and then I see this line:

```
} elsif($text =~ /^slaps $levbot_nick/i) {
```

- But what `/^` and `/i` do?
- Why to use they?

I think this is regular expression, I'm right?

Comment: Take a look at `perldoc perlrequick` for a reasonably gentle introduction to regular expressions in Perl. It's a big subject, but this will get you started. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html

Comment: If you're going to deal with Perl, start with Learning Perl (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- `/` Delimiter denoting start of regex (The char `/` is not part of the regex)
- `^` Matches the start of a line
- `/` Delimiter for the end of the regex (not part of the regex)
- `i` Flag to make the regex case insensitive

Other flags possible are:

- `g` Global
- `s` Dot matches new line characters
- `x` Extended - ignores whitespaces in the pattern and allows comments
- `m` Multiline mode.

Comment: Well, the / starts the match operator, not the regex. It's a slight but important difference.

Comment: I don't know Perl and I am not aware of the difference - can you please explain/give a link?

Comment: The stuff inside the slashes is the actual "regular expression". The slashes merely indicate where the expression starts and stops, but are not a part of the actual expression.

Comment: @Amarghosh: the regular expression is the pattern that you're looking to match. The match operator is the syntax that tells the Perl interpreter: here comes a regex. In Perl, the match operator is normally delimited by '/' at start and end, but you can use delimiters (e.g., `m{^foo}`). See the section "Regexp Quote like operators" in perldoc perlop for the gory details. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators

Comment: That was exactly my understanding - and that's exactly what I meant by `delimiter`

Comment: Looking at Amarghosh's answer again, though, I'm not sure myself what brian objects to. Amarghosh didn't say that `/` was part of the regular expression; he said it denoted the start of the regex. That seems pretty reasonable to me here.

Comment: @Amarghosh: yeah, I reread your answer and came to that same conclusion. I think "delimiter denoting the start of the regex" is reasonable, but there may be a subtlety I'm missing as well.

Comment: @Telemachus Added clarification anyway.

Comment: Amarghosh: gsx are not all flags that are allowed. 'e' and 'm' are important.

Comment: i, m, s, x, and the mostly-useless o to control matching; c, e, and g to control substitution (hey, that's a C major chord!)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

- The `/` on either side mark the pattern's beginning and end.
- The `^` at the start of the patten means "only match this at the beginning of the string, and nowhere else."
- The `i` after the end of the pattern is a modifier, it means "be case-insensitive when matching this", since the default is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) documentation. Briefly, `/^` matches the start of a line, and `/i` means it's case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Thats a regular expression

```
/^slaps $levbot_nick/i
```

/^ means starts with (actually ^ alone)

/i means ignore case (i alone after / /)

first and last / slashes are boundary of regex

Answer (score 3):

`/^` matches the beginning of a line.

`/i` means case insensitive search.

Answer (score 2):

`/^` beginning of the line
`/i` ignore size of the letters

Answer (score 0):

This syntax in Perl was inspired by awk's /xxx/ Pattern matching feature.

Answer (score 0):

1. ^(carat) symbol denotes regex 'starting with'. Here the pattern should start with slaps.

   > /i denotes **case insensitive** search
2. To match pattern

Yes, you are right. It is regular expression.

In your case matching pattern is starting with slaps along with value in *levbot_nick* variable.